# How do I make binding work for a list property in a custom control?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox

Since the `ListBox` doesn't allow you to two-way bind to its `SelectedItems` property, I created my own custom control `MultipleSelectionListBox`. It adds the property `BindableSelectedItems`, which lets you bind an `IEnumerable` to it.

```
public class MultipleSelectionListBox : ListBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BindableSelectedItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BindableSelectedItems",
            typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(MultipleSelectionListBox),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(IEnumerable),
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnBindableSelectedItemsChanged));

    public IEnumerable BindableSelectedItems
    {
        get => (IEnumerable)GetValue(BindableSelectedItemsProperty);
        set => SetValue(BindableSelectedItemsProperty, value);
    }

    protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
        BindableSelectedItems = SelectedItems;
    }

    private static void OnBindableSelectedItemsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is MultipleSelectionListBox listBox)
            listBox.SetSelectedItems(listBox.BindableSelectedItems);
    }
}
```

The view model's property I'm binding it to is of type `IEnumerable<string>`, and the binding doesn't work. The view model's property always receives `null` when the list box's selection is changed.

If I change the type of `BindableSelectedItems` to `IEnumerable<string>`, then the binding works. This makes me believe that the binding doesn't like the type mismatch. Am I stuck having to explicitly specify the type of the list items, or is there a way to keep it general? It would be nice to be able to use the same `MultipleSelectionListBox` for items of other types.

Comment: Are you missing something? In both the scenarios, you'd mentioned that ViewModel property is of `IEnumerable<String>` type.

Comment: @dhilmathy Yes, thank you. I corrected the question.

Comment: try using IEnumerable<T> or even IEnumerable<object> everywhere you using IEnumerable here

Comment: "Since the ListBox doesn't allow you to two-way bind to its SelectedItems property". Do you mean that you cant set the selectedItem from the vm? You can do that. You can both set it from view and from viemodel. Is your vm implementing  INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: @GianlucaConte There's no problem with `SelectedItem`. The problem is with `SelectedItems` (note the plural).

Answer (score 1):

This is because, `SelectedItems` will be always of type `System.Collections.IList {System.Windows.Controls.SelectedItemCollection}`. So, when you tried using `IEnumerable` you're directly assigning the `SelectedItems` to `BindableSelectedItems`. Where the cast is invalid and it was sent `null` to your `ViewModel` property.

Where as, when you set the type as `IEnumerable<string>` you would've casted `SelectedItems` to `string` collection like `BindableSelectedItems = SelectedItems.Cast<string>();` Which matches the type of the property in `ViewModel` and it worked.

I see that you want to make it generic. For that you can try something like,

**ListBox Control code**

```
public class MultipleSelectionListBox : ListBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BindableSelectedItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BindableSelectedItems",
            typeof(IList), typeof(MultipleSelectionListBox),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(IList),
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnBindableSelectedItemsChanged));

    public IList BindableSelectedItems
    {
        get => (IList)GetValue(BindableSelectedItemsProperty);
        set => SetValue(BindableSelectedItemsProperty, value);
    }

    protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSelectionChanged(e);

        IList selectedItemsList = BindableSelectedItems;
        if (selectedItemsList == null)
            selectedItemsList = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(ItemsSource.GetType());
        selectedItemsList.Clear();

        foreach (var item in SelectedItems)
            selectedItemsList.Add(item);

        BindableSelectedItems = selectedItemsList;
    }

    private static void OnBindableSelectedItemsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is MultipleSelectionListBox listBox)
            listBox.SetSelectedItems(listBox.BindableSelectedItems);
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable Items { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable SelectedItems { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Items = new List<string> { "Test", "Test1" };
        SelectedItems = new List<string> { "Test" };
    }
}
```

I'd tested with common scenarios and it's working fine.

Comment: It does work in your scenario where `Items` and `SelectedItems` are both `List<string>`, but it didn't work in my scenario where `Items` is `string[]`. Also, is there a reason you assign `selectedItemsList` to `BindableSelectedItems` and then clear it? Why not always assign `selectedItemsList` to the instance created by `Activator`?

Comment: @redcurry Yeah, I see you. Array will be of fixed size and it'll not work. All other generic collection types (`IList`) should work. Regarding the second question, there can be cases where `Items` and `SelectedItems` be of different types (like `List<string>` and `ObservableCollection<string>`). So, for that case, i am trying to use the same collection type at `IList selectedItemsList = BindableSelectedItems;` and `selectedItemsList.Clear();`  to clear any existing items.